# I'm having trouble getting an observer to fire after trying to hook to the aschroder_smtppro_before_send event; any ideas?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, email, smtp

I've been working a bit now on a little project to implement a simple blacklist for *Magento CE 1.9.x* and *Aschroder's* **SMTPPro** email extension.  I've been in a couple of different directions with this, at first thinking that I was going to have to override `getTemplateSubject()`, and potentially some other methods, in order to intercept an outgoing email, as I don't believe that (sans-**SMTPPro**) Magento has any events that fire on dispatching of an email.  As a sidenote, corrections on any misconceptions that I may be having in this posting are very much appreciated.

So I've gone ahead and focused on tying in to **SMTPPro**'s `aschroder_smtppro_before_send` event to try to fire my code.  I want to eventually check the recipient address, look for a substring, and can any emails matching that criteria (potentially with a message to an admin) at some point in the future.  Right now, however, I can't even get the code to give me a `var_dump` just to know that it's even firing.  I did try tying the code to a different event, at one point (namely `controller_action_predispatch`, which broke the site in the way that I was betting on), but I'm not sure where that leaves me for what is going wrong right now.  Unless the documentation I've seen is incorrect and **SMTPPro** doesn't have the event defined or firing.

So here is what I've done.

in *$INST_HOME/app/code/local/Myorganization* I've created the tree:

> drwxrwsr-x 3 dgetsman   src 4096 Jul  1 03:38 Core.bak drwxrwsr-x 2
>   scriptuser src 4096 Jul  2 20:57 etc  drwxrwsr-x 2 scriptuser src 4096
>   Jul  1 01:24 Helper drwxrwsr-x 2 dgetsman   src 4096 Jul  2 20:42
>   Model
>
> Emailblacklist/Core.bak:  total 4  drwxrwsr-x 2 dgetsman src 4096 Jul 
>   2 20:30 Model
>
> Emailblacklist/Core.bak/Model:  total 4
>   -rw-rw-r-- 1 dgetsman src 921 Jul  1 03:41 Email.php
>
> Emailblacklist/etc: total 4
>   -rw-rw-r-- 1 scriptuser src 998 Jul  2 20:57 config.xml
>
> Emailblacklist/Helper: total 4
>   -rw-rw-r-- 1 scriptuser src 86 Jul  1 01:24 Data.php
>
> Emailblacklist/Model: total 4
>   -rw-rw-r-- 1 dgetsman src 201 Jul  2 02:05 Observer.php

Please note that *Core.bak* only includes some vestigial code that I was working on from when I was still attempting to go about this via overriding the `getTemplateSubject()` method.

Contents of *Emailblacklist/etc/config.xml* follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <config>
    <modules>
        <Myorganization_Emailblacklist>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Myorganization_Emailblacklist>
    </modules>
    <global>
      <helpers>
        <emailblacklist>
            <class>Myorganization_Emailblacklist_Helper</class>
        </emailblacklist>
      </helpers>
      <models>
        <myorganization_emailblacklist>
          <class>Myorganization_Emailblacklist_Model</class>
        </myorganization_emailblacklist>
      </models>
      <events>
        <!-- for debugging purposes
             <controller_action_predispatch> -->
        <aschroder_smtppro_before_send>
          <observers>
            <myorganization_emailblacklist>
              <class>myorganization_emailblacklist/observer</class>
              <method>watchEmails</method>
            </myorganization_emailblacklist>
          </observers>
        </aschroder_smtppro_before_send>
        <!-- debugging: </controller_action_predispatch> -->
      </events>
    </global>
  </config>
```

Contents of *Emailblacklist/Helper/Data.php* follow:

```
<?php
class Uselite_Emailblacklist_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {

}
```

Contents of *Emailblacklist/Model/Observer.php* follow:

```
<?php
class Uselite_Emailblacklist_Model_Observer {
    public function watchEmails(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $order = $observer->getEvent();

        die(var_dump($order));

    }
}
```

As can be assumed from the aforementioned code, I'm hoping at this point just to get a dump of `$order` at this point.  Absolutely anything helpful will be very much appreciated.  Thanks for your time and consideration.  Please also feel free to let me know if I've forgotten to include any information that will be helpful to the troubleshooting process here.

Answer (score 2):

In Magento 1.9 transactional emails are scheduled and then sent from a cronjob, so you will never see the result of `var_dump()` unless you trigger the cron manually from shell. You can use `Mage::log()` instead to prove that your observer is triggered.

Comment: Thank you!  I was wondering if a cron scenario might have something to do with that, but stopped considering it at some point awhile ago.  Good to know!

Comment: Now that I've got logging actually turned on, and now that I've got things configured to dump via `Mage::log()`, I'm still not finding the dump that I'm looking for anywhere.  I've tried some alteration of the tag in _config.xml_ from _myorganization_emailblacklist_ to _myorganization_emailblacklist_model_observer_, for instance (which someone else suggested) and it's still not changing anything, either.  I am, however, seeing some unrelated stuff spewing into _$APPHOME/var/log_, though, so I know logging is now working.  Any other ideas, perchance?

Comment: any suggestions on how to get _cron.sh_ running manually from within the shell?  I've been working with `/bin/sh /server/public/myorganization/current/cron.sh`, but it appears that something in the environment is preventing it from running properly.  Lack of output is hindering diagnosis of this.  I've tried it from within the root directory, within the _$APPHOME_ directory, and the home that it normally executes in, AFAIK.  Doesn't fire off an email, though the second I put it back in the standard cron all seems fine.  Any suggestions on manual triggering?

Comment: For monitoring crons, I highly suggest using [`Aoe_Scheduler`](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler), one of the first extension I install in every store. It comes with a `scheduler_cron.sh` which is way more useful than the default cron.sh. Otherwise, you could run `php cron.php -mdefault` instead of `cron.sh`, this way you'll at least see some output

Comment: Though that (php command line) managed to get the email sent out to me, it still fails to produce any output.  I guess it's time to look into that extension.  :|